# Solve Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can use some help with the following ode's:
1) $2x^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2$

2) $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 + x \cdot (\frac{dy}{dx})-y=0$

Can you give me a usefull substitution? Thanx in advance!

Comment: There is something *very very* wrong with this(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(y')%5E2+%2B+xy'+%2B+y%3D0)

Answer (score 0):

For (1), substitute $y = u x$. Then $y^\prime = u + u^\prime x$ and the equation becomes 
$$xu^\prime = {1\over 2}(1-u)^2$$
which is separable.

For (2), differentiate both sides to obtain $y^{\prime\prime}(2y^\prime + x) = 0$. So either $y^{\prime\prime}=0$ or $2y^\prime + x = 0$. This leads to the two distinct solutions $y = c^2+c x$ and $y = -\frac{1}{4}x^2$.

(Interestingly, Mathematica 8 misses the solution $y =-\frac{1}{4}x^2$.)

Comment: Comment: Substitute the $y'=xu'+u$ expression in $(1)$ results in $xu'=\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Apologies @user139746 - my factored form was incorrect. Corrected above.

Comment: When differentiate Diff. Equation (2) at both sides to x (?) I obtain, by the chain rule,: $y''(2y'+x)$ but also the derivative $frac{dy}{dx}=y'$ by the derivative of the last y. Is this correct?

Comment: @user139746 I think you missed an application of the product rule. $2y^\prime y^{\prime\prime} + x y^{\prime\prime} + y^\prime \cdot 1 - y^\prime$. The last two terms cancel.